Is there a difference between talk someone around, bring someone around and talk someone into?
I also had a question about the differences between these three phrasal verbs. I understand that "to talk around" and "to bring around" have to do with changing one's mind, but how do they differ exactly ? What's more, how does "to talk into" differ from the latter two ?
Thank you.

Bring someone around means have them visit casually, or convince them over time. Talk into means convince/persuade. Never heard of to talk around except to skirt the subject.

IMO "bring around" typically means from opposition to agreement, "talk into" from neutral to agreement.

"To bring around" is to persuade someone to a view.  I note that I have seen examples of this not being verbal.   For instance, someone being brought about by seeing how miserable the decision had made the children.  The children did not have argue the point, just be very miserable.
"To talk around" can mean to persuade someone into a view -- verbally.  It can also mean to avoid a subject, so care is needed.
"To talk into" is to persuade someone to an action.
